# Creating a MultipartFormDataInput object for Java jUnit testing

Tags: java, junit, resteasy, multipartform-data

uI've got a Resteasy webservice method that takes a MultipartFormDataInput object as its parm, and pulls lots of information out of it.  I'd like to write a jUnit test for this method, but I've been unable to find any way to create this object and put dummy data in it so I can call my webservice method directly.  The service method extracts the data from the form like this...

```
@POST
@Path("/requestDeviceCode")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public DeviceCodeModel requestDeviceCode(final MultipartFormDataInput inputMultipart) {

    // process the form data - only field in the form is the token
    Map<String, List<InputPart>> formData = null; // we'll put the form data in here
    formData = inputMultipart.getFormDataMap();

    String token = null;
    try {
        token = formData.get("Token").get(0).getBodyAsString();
        this._logger.debug("Pulled encrypted token out of input form, it's " + token);
```

and that works fine, but trying to create an object to pass as a parm to 'requestDeviceCode' has me stymied.  I've tried variations of this...

```
        // create a multipartForm (input to the service POST) and add the "token" string to it
        MultipartFormDataOutput newForm = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
        newForm.addFormData("Token", encryptedXMLString, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);

        _service.requestDeviceCode((MultipartFormDataInput) newForm);
```

but it's just not doing it (this particular error is that I can't cast the Output form to an Input form).  I haven't been able to find a way to create a new MultiPartFormDataInput and add data to it.

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Are you attempting to test the ability of your code to extract data from the MultiPartFormDataInput, or test that your program correctly uses the data it got from the object?

Comment: For this, I'm testing the ability of my code to extract the data from the form properly.  I've got other tests that call the method that uses the token pulled from the form, and those are working, but for completeness's sake I'd like to have an integration test that tests this service end-to-end, hence trying to create & populate the MultipartFormDataInput object.

Comment: Wondering if you got any further with this...

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon a similar problem when trying to unit test my RestEasy WebService's method that accepts MultipartFormDataInput.

What you could do, is to mock the **MultipartFormDataInput** to return a prepared map with mocked **InputPart** for each form parameter you're expecting to receive.

Possible solution (using JUnit/Mockito):

```
@Test
public void testService() {
    // given
    MultipartFormDataInput newForm = mock(MultipartFormDataInput.class);
    InputPart token = mock(InputPart.class);

    Map<String, List<InputPart>> paramsMap = new HashMap<>();
    paramsMap.put("Token", Arrays.asList(token));        

    when(newForm.getFormDataMap()).thenReturn(paramsMap);
    when(token.getBodyAsString()).thenReturn("expected token param body");
    // when
    DeviceCodeModel actual = _service.requestDeviceCode(newForm);
    // then
    // verifications and assertions go here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing an integration test?
Start jetty or Tomcat embeded in your tests and let it run your REST service.
As HTTP-Client I would take Apache HttpComponents Client, see the [Tutorial](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/) and the MultiPart client example on the [examples page](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html).

Comment: it's a possibility, but I was hoping to find something I could execute on the fly like the other tests, rather than something that would require a server startup each time.

Comment: You can still automate this and integrate this in your Continuous Integration by using the maven [failsafe plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html) together with automatic start and shutdown of Jetty around your integration-test phase, see *Automatic execution of the plugin* in the maven [Jetty Plugin documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin).